# Checking a NTFS drive with Linux

Tags: disk

Does somebody know if there is something like/similar to the typical Windows **`chkdsk`** or **`scandisk`** utilities (to check NTFS drives, of course) into Linux (Ubuntu)?

Which? Where? How?

Answer (score 18):

Yes. Run:

```
ntfsfix /dev/sdxx
```

This command comes from `ntfsprogs`.

Do be warned (from the man page):

> ntfsfix is a utility that fixes some common NTFS problems. **ntfsfix is NOT a Linux version of chkdsk**. It only repairs some fundamental NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal file and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows.

(emphasis mine)